# .htaccess password request background page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, apache2, .htpasswd

[image: Password Site]

I've added a working `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` file to a sub-site of my webserver (Apache2.4+php7.4 on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ using raspios).
This is working totally fine (as you can see in the picture above)...
But I'd like to know if there is a way to change the white background to a html/php file or just redirect another page as background page while the password prompt is still shown?

Comment: You can theoretically specify an ErrorDocument for the 401 status code, but I think browsers won't actually show it. Browsers keep showing the document they had shown _before_, or a white page if there was none. (So that _could_ perhaps be a way of achieving it, that you serve an unprotected document first, and then have that redirect - JavaScript, or meta refresh - to a resource within the protected realm.)